# [OData Source [280]] Error: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager

Tags: ssis

I am trying to load a Sharepoint List ,The connection manager works fine and tests successfully. When I try to run the package (running in local),it fails immediately with the error "[OData Source [280]] Error: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager."

I tried changing https to http.

I changed proxy internet settings.

I tried passing the username,password and URL.(I am using Microsoft Online Services and my credentials have access to the URL).

Also tried 64bitRuntime to false

I changed the Keep active status to true and timeout >600. Nothing works.

Can somebody please help? Using VS2017